# Neo4J: clause NOT not working as expected

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Working with Neo4J moovie graph, when I execute this query:

```
match (p:Person)-[ai:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
where not (p.name in ['Keanu Reeves'])
return m limit 1
```

I am getting movies where Keanu Reeves acted in like 'The Matrix Revolutions'.
I assumed that the query should return movies in which Keanu Reeves did not act. 
What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to get the movies where Keanu did not act?

Comment: Multiple people act in a single movie (...generally), and you're counting over actors-in-movies. You want to count over *movies*, filtering for those where *none* of the actors are Keanu Reeves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Patrick Bösch answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46886030/6835358) works, but it is building a [cartesian product](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/cross-product-cypher-queries-will-not-perform-well/) between `(p:Person)` and `(m:Movie)` nodes.

The below query will do the same job, but avoiding cartesian products (and in a more clear way, I think):

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE NOT (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(:Person {name : 'Keanu Reeves'})
RETURN m
```

The query will `MATCH` all movies avoiding ones that have a relation `:ACTED_IN` with a `:Person` node that name is equal to Keanu Reeves.

**UPDATE**

From comments:

> What if it is not just Keanu Reeves but keanu Reeves AND Robin
>   Williams?

Then you can do:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p:Person)
WITH m, collect(p) as actors
WHERE NONE (actor in actors WHERE actor.name IN ['Keanu Reeves', 'Robin Williams'])
RETURN m
```

Or:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE NONE(n in ['Keanu Reeves', 'Robin Williams']
    WHERE (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(:Person {name:n}))
RETURN m
```

Comment: What if it is not just Keanu Reeves but keanu Reeves AND Robin Williams?

Comment: @Dexter you will need MATCH these nodes first, like: `MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name IN ['Keanu Reeves', 'Robin Williams']
MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE NOT (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p)
RETURN DISTINCT m`

Comment: @Dexter Also, I added a `DISTINCT` before `m` to avoid duplicate results.

Comment: That query seems to not work since it returns movies where keanu OR Robin did not act. When executin the query the result includes for example The matrix, a movie where Keanu acted but not Robin

Comment: @Dexter oh right! I understand now. Try it: `MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p:Person)
WITH m, collect(p) as actors WHERE NONE (actor in actors WHERE actor.name IN  ['Keanu Reeves', 'Robin Williams'])
RETURN m`

Comment: @Dexter or this (avoiding `WITH`): `MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE NONE(n in ['Keanu Reeves', 'Robin Williams'] WHERE (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(:Person {name:n}))
RETURN m`

Answer (score 1):

If you like to get all movies where Keanu Reeves doesn't acted in you have to exclude this relationship from the result otherwise you will get the movies where Keanu Reeves and any other of the actors acted in too.

Get all movies where Keanu Reeves didn't acted in:

```
MATCH (p:Person),(m:Movie)
WHERE p.name IN ['Keanu Reeves']
AND NOT ((p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m))
RETURN m
```

Comment: Also, `p.name IN ['Keanu Reeves']` is overkill. Just use `p.name = 'Keanu Reeves'`, or, for more clarity, `MATCH (p:Person{name: 'Keanu Reeves'}), (m:Movie)`